# Instantsearch Google Places Autocomplete Helper not part of instance

Tags: google-places-api, algolia, instantsearch.js

I implemented Google Places Autocomplete into an active Instantsearch instance.

```
mlsearch.addWidget(googlePlacesWidget);
```

The helper function looks like this:

```
var googlePlacesWidget = {
    init: function(opts) {

        var options = {
            types: ['(regions)']
        };

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            document.getElementById('pac-input'),
            options
        );

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChanged);

        function onPlaceChanged() {
            var location = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location;
            var lat = location.lat();
            var lng = location.lng();
            opts.helper.setQueryParameter('aroundLatLng', lat + ',' + lng);
            opts.helper.setQueryParameter('aroundRadius', $('select#radius_changed').val());
            opts.helper.search();
        }
    }
};
```

This works fine filtering a list of members.

But it seems that this helper is not part of the instantsearch instance for some reason. I have a reset widget which works fine for any other filter, but it does not show up when setting a location. So the problem is, I can not reset it. Ideally it would also reset the results when the user clears the input, but there is no callback other than `place_changed` via Google API.

How can I make this a widget that is being recognised as an actual filter, and active the reset button upon search.

Just for completion, this is the reset widget (again, works fine with any other filter / widget implemented):

```
mlsearch.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.clearAll({
        container: '#clearfilter',
        templates: {
            link: 'Reset'
        },
        autoHideContainer: true,
        clearsQuery: true,
    })
);
```

Comment: I didn't find an easy way to implement it with the `clearAll` widget. But to clear the input when the value is empty you can register a listener on the `input` event. Then when the value is empty you can reset the `aroundLatLng` parameter. Here is [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rm0lk548lq) that show how to implement it.

Comment: @SamuelVaillant Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much. :)